# using C# linq to write XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to modfiy an XML file and know next to nothing about XML, see the following snippet.  I was handed some code using linq so I'm trying to utilize that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <RadanCompoundDocument xmlns="http://www.radan.com/ns/rcd">
  <RadanAttributes>
  <Group class="custom" name="Manufacturing" desc="These attributes are the manufacturing     properties of the file."
    ord="6">
      <Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1">
    <Valid perm="e" max="20"/>
      </Attr>
      <Attr num="120" name="Thickness" desc="Thickness." type="r" ord="2">
    <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999"/>
    ....
```

I want to set a value for the line containing "Attrib num="119", as shown below:

```
<Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1" value="Material1">
    <Valid perm="e" max="20"/>
  </Attr>
```

I am using the following code in c# to search for the correct attribute and set the value:

```
XDocument symDoc = XDocument.Load(SymFilePath);
XElement temp = symDoc.Descendants(symNameSpace + ATT_ELEMENT)
  .Where(t => t.Attribute(NUM_ATTRIBUTE).Value == MATERIAL_ATT_NUMBER).FirstOrDefault();
temp.SetValue(MaterialName)
```

This works to set the value, but then I lose the last part of my XML ("Valid perm="e" max="20"/>"). The attrib 119 line now shows as below:

```
<Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1">Steel, Mild</Attr>
```

So my question is this: how can I set this value without losing the last part of my XML?

So after doing some more research I believe what I want to do is just add another attribute to the existing element without losing the child element. Thanks for the answers so far but I was misleading on my original question, I don't think they apply to what I'm trying to do.

Sorry for all the confusion, the first answer did what I needed to do anyways.

Comment: Can you change the expected format of your XML? Typically you want each element to either contain elements *or* text, but not a combination of each.

Comment: you are setting the value for <Attr num="119" name="Material" desc="Material." type="s" ord="1"> </Attr>  That is everything between the opening and closing tag.  How do you want the XML to look when you are done?

Comment: CLARIFICATION:  temp.SetValue is not working the way I want it to.  All I want to do is add the text 'value="Material1"' at the end of the existing text.  (As my second code snippet shows)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
temp.SetAttributeValue("value", MaterialName);
```

If you want to have it as XML element value you will lose the inner element 'Valid'. You cannot have both inner text and inner XML element.

Answer (score 0):

Intead of `.SetValue()` try using `.Add()` or `.AddFirst()`:

```
temp.AddFirst(MaterialName)
```